# order mysql query result in decreasing order

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, sql-order-by

I am trying to create a table for marks and rank team in decreasing order.
i tried this.

```
$q = $db_con-> prepare("
SELECT @s:=@s+1 serial_number, t_name,name,marks FROM team,user,(SELECT @s:=0) AS s WHERE user.u_id=team.u_id ORDER BY marks DESC");
```

Above query displays result in DESC order of marks but serial numbers get altered. 
like..

```
sr no    team name   marks

 3          A         30
 1          B         20
 2          C         10
```

How to get serial numbers in order?

Comment: you are using only `ORDER BY marks DESC`

Comment: DO you want to order by SrNo or marks?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK i want to order by marks , but sr. no (as a rank for team)..it should be in order 1,2,3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT @s:=@s+1 serial_number, t_name, name, marks 
FROM (SELECT t_name, name, marks 
      FROM team t INNER JOIN user u ON u.u_id=t.u_id 
      ORDER BY marks DESC
     ) AS A, (SELECT @s:=0) AS s;
```

Comment: Thanks...this is the perfect solution. Would you explain why i have to use Inner Join?

Comment: @HungryDB You're most welcome... You were using CROSS JOIN and then converting that CROSS JOIN into INNER JOIN by condition in WHERE clause. Instead of doing that you can explicitly define INNER JOIN on tables. Performance of INNER JOIN on CROSS JOIN is always better.

Comment: ahh, ok. 'll remember this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the serial number in a subquery and then sort by the marks:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT @s:=@s+1 as serial_number, t_name, name, marks
      FROM team join
           user
           on user.u_id=team.u_id cross join
           (SELECT @s:=0)s
    ) t
ORDER BY marks DESC;
```

However, you are not ordering by anything for the serial number.  You really need to because the ordering of tables is indeterminate.

I also fixed your join syntax to use proper ANSI standard joins.

Comment: It does sorts serial number but in descending order, i need it in ascending order. Can we make any changes in above query to do that?